# Statusbar information for i3 window manager in ubuntu 11.10

Tags: ubuntu, window-manager

I'm having one HELL of a time configuring [i3](http://i3wm.org/). I love the window manager, but I can't seem to get it to display me some sort of statusbar.

Ive been hacking about with dzen2 in my i3 config file, but to no avail.

Anyone have a simple conf file / instructions to set this up?

All I really want in the i3 bar is:

```
(left aligned)[workspaces]

(right aligned)[load][vpn yes/no][date][time]
```

Help?

Comment: I gave up setting up i3 + conky + dzen2 combination on Ubuntu some time ago. There was a wrong dzen2 version or something. Check these links: [Bug #590350 (Ubuntu)](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/dzen2/+bug/590350) and [Bug #561286 (Debian)](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=561286).

Answer (score 1):

In case somebody is looking for this, there is now a statusbar integrated with i3, which fits your purposes. More about this here:

- http://i3wm.org/i3status/
- http://i3wm.org/docs/userguide.html#_configuring_i3bar

It's simple to configure and the standard config already comes with most of the things the OP is looking for. Highly recommended.